# MS Access Best Practice for Storing Combo Box Values in which multiple values can be used

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I am designing a small hospital database.

The doctor has given me a list of various values that can apply to a text field.
for Example a list of 20 diseases out of which more than one can apply in the diagnosis text box.
there 50+ such lists for various fields in the whole database.

Ms Access does not let Multiple value List be edited so what i have designed is as follows.
First the doctor selects a value from the combo box drop down list and to it more can be added as LimitToList is set to YES. Then an "ADD" Button near the list is linked which concats the new value to the older value of the text box using a piece of VBA code onClick.

```
Dim add As String
Dim past As String
past = [Forms]![Exam]![diagnosis]
add = [Forms]![Exam]![diseases list]
[Forms]![Exam]![diagnosis] = past + add + ", "
Me.Refresh
```

Here the list values are stored in the form only.

**My question is , is this the best practice which can be used in the scenario?**
Also, when i link the list data to a table as there are varying number of records in each row( for different fields), white spaces also show up in the combo box list.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create 3 tables
1 "Diagnosis"
2 "Disease"
3 a junction Table "DiagnosisXDisease"

**Schema**

1
DiagnosisID | Diagnosis

2
DiseaseID | Disease

3
DiagnosisID | DiseaseID

You can then have the user select one from the first combo and have a continuous form below where you add a record for each related value.
Where you have a combo box to choose from the list
This way you can add as many as you need.

---

http://www.599cd.com/tips/access/form-subform/

http://www.599cd.com/tips/access/combo-box-select-customer/

http://www.599cd.com/tips/access/relational-tables/

Comment: Thank You for your reply. This would work if only i had Diagnosis and Disease to work on. But as i said in the question, there are 50+ such scenarios in the Database.